# SMTP configuration in PHP Mail configuration issue

Tags: email, mail-server

We have integrated mail in my php in internal server.

Our client has given email id admin@automate.com.sg mail id.

But the **automate.com.sg** domain is not running (when I check it in internet).
Using outlook express they are sending mail through **admin@automate.com.sg** and receiving mail .

**In outlook express:**
**Account Type :** POP3
**Incoming Mail server :** pop.gmail.com
**Outgoing mail server (SMTP) :**smtp.gmail.com

I want to know without running the automate.com.sg how the mail is send/receive.
Should I do any modification in coding or network side?

Comment: I don't get your point

Comment: mail has to go their external email server, admin mail id is admin@automate.com.sg if we send mail to this mail id, mail not getting delivered. They are using  Incoming Mail server : pop.gmail.com and Outgoing mail server (SMTP) : smtp.gmail.com, In this case what i have to do? should i change i coding level.? or how can i  solve this